How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k \ln(t))}{\sqrt{t}} \left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\} \, dt $
I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\ln\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{t}}\,
\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\} \, dt,
$$ where $\left\{\cdots\right\}$ denotes fractional part function and $k$ is a real number.
Let $t = e^u$, then $dt = e^u \, du$ and the integral becomes:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ku)}{\sqrt{e^u}}\{e^{-u}\} e^u \, du=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(ku) \{e^{-u}\} e^{u/2} \, du.$$
The fractional part function $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ may be written as:
$$ \{x\} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{ n}.$$
So the above integral becomes:
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(ku) \{e^{-u}\} e^{u/2} \, du
\\[3mm] = & \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \sin(ku) e^{u/2}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left(2 \pi n e^{-u}\right)}{ n}\right]  \, du.
\end{align}
Is this correct?  What after this?

Please do not delete and repost. Instead, delete this repost, and improve (and undelete) your original post.

It seems simpler to consider $$L \equiv \int_0^\infty t^{ik-\frac{3}{2}}{t}dt$$ where your integral is the value given by $\operatorname{Im}\left{\overline{L}\right}$

@Abezhiko $\frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}{t^2} = t^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

Firstly, let's replace the sine function by a complex exponential, so that your integral corresponds to the imaginary part of the following integral :
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(ik\ln t)}{\sqrt{t}} \left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\} \,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty t^{ik-1/2} \left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}  \,\mathrm{d}t 
$$
The latter expression represents the Mellin transform of $\{1/t\}$ evaluated at $s = \frac{1}{2}+ik$. Moreover, one knows that $\mathscr{M}[f(1/x)](s) = \mathscr{M}[f(x)](-s)$. In consequence, one needs to determine the Mellin transform of the fractional part.
It can be done as it follows :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{M}[\{x\}](s) 
   &= \mathscr{M}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{\pi n}\right](s) & (1) \\
   &= -\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{\mathscr{M}[\sin(2\pi nx)](s)}{\pi n} & (2) \\
   &= -\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{2}{(2\pi n)^{s+1}} \mathscr{M}[\sin x](s) &(3) \\
   &= -\frac{2}{(2\pi)^{s+1}}\zeta(1+s)\Gamma(s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right) & (4) \\
   &= \frac{\zeta(-s)}{s} & (5)
\end{align}
$$
where we used :

$(1)$ the Fourier series of the fractional part, which you recalled ;
$(2)$ the linearity of the Mellin transform (see also the side note below) ;
$(3)$ the property $\mathscr{M}[f(ax)](s) = a^{-s}\mathscr{M}[f(x)](s)$ ;
$(4)$ the Mellin transform of the sine function, i.e. $\mathscr{M}[\sin x](s) = \Gamma(s)\sin(\pi s/2)$ ;
$(5)$ the relation $\Gamma(1+s) = s\Gamma(s)$, as well as Riemann's functional equation.

Consequently, one has in the end :
$$
\boxed{
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(k\ln t)}{\sqrt{t}} \{1/t\} \,\mathrm{d}t 
   = \left.\operatorname{Im}\mathscr{M}[\{x\}](-s)\right|_{s=\frac{1}{2}+ik} 
   = -\operatorname{Im}\frac{\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+ik)}{\frac{1}{2}+ik}
}
$$

Side note.
The constant term inside the Fourier series doesn't contribute to the Mellin transform of the fractional part. Indeed, the sine function can be decomposed into complex exponentials, in such a way that we are left with the following kind of expression (up to suitable normalization) :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{M}[e^{-x}-1](s)
   &= \mathscr{M}\left[\int_0^x e^{-y} \,\mathrm{d}y\right](s) \\
   &= s^{-1}\mathscr{M}[e^{-x}](s+1) \\
   &= s^{-1}\Gamma(s+1) \\
   &= \Gamma(s) \\
   &= \mathscr{M}[e^{-x}](s)
\end{align}
$$
Nevertheless, due to convergence issues, this phenomenon takes place only when $-1 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < 0$. Yet, $\operatorname{Re}(-s) = -\frac{1}{2}$ in the present case (since we are interested in the Mellin transform of $\{1/t\}$ at the end, we have to consider $-s$ instead), that is why it turns out to be a valid move.

IMO, it is a really surprising representation of $\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+ik)$.

@Yalikesi  Riemann's zeta function and fractional part are indeed related : see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_Representation_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function_in_terms_of_Fractional_Part for example.
